# Python - Limit amount of data subprocess.Popen can produce

Tags: python, subprocess

I found lots of similar questions asking size of an object at run time in python. Some of the answers suggests to set a limit on amount of memory of sub-process. I do not want to set a limit on memory of sub-process. Here is what I want --

I'm using `subprocess.Popen()` to execute an external program. I can, very well, get standard output and error with `process.stdout.readlines()` and `process.stderr.readlines()` after the process is complete.

I have a problem when an erroneous program gets into an infinite loop and keeps producing output. Since `subprocess.Popen()` stores output data in memory this infinite loop quickly eats up entire memory and program slows down.

One solution is that I can run the command with timeout. But programs take variable time to complete. Large timeout, for a program taking small time and having an infinite loop, defeats the purpose of having it.

Is there any simple way where I can put an upper limit say 200MB on amount of data the command can produce? If it exceeds the limit command should get killed.

Comment: Once the pipe buffer is full the child process does not just slow down. It stops completely until you read the data. If you need to read more than one pipe concurrently then you could use threads or `select` or `fcntl` modules to read the pipes without blocking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: It is not `subprocess.Popen()` storing the data, but it is the pipe between "us" and "our" subprocess.

You shouldn't use `readlines()` in this case as this will indefinitely buffer the data and only at the end return them as a list (in this case, it is indeed this function which stores the data).

If you do something like

```
bytes = lines = 0
for line in process.stdout:
    bytes += len(line)
    lines += 1
    if bytes > 200000000 or lines > 10000:
        # handle the described situation
        break
```

you can act as wanted in your question. But you shouldn't forget to kill the subprocess afterwards in order to stop it producing further data.

But if you want to take care of `stderr` as well, you'd have to try to replicate `process.communicate()`'s behaviour with `select()` etc., and act appropriately.

Comment: A quick note:  if you do a `break` inside your `if bytes ... or lines...:`, per this example, you will stop "consuming" data from the pipe, and your subprocess will block trying to write to the full stdout pipe.

At this point, you should either continue to consume (and discard) the data or kill the child process.

Comment: @fmoo Completely right. Consubing and discarding data could become lengthy as the subprocess might be in an endless loop, but killing it seems to be appropriate.

Comment: it might fail if OP needs to read `stderr` also. If child process fills up the stderr pipe buffer then the parent blocks forever trying to read from `process.stdout` while the child process tries to write to its stderr.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be an easy answer to what you want

http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl2_setrlimit.htm

rlimit has a flag to limit memory, CPU or number of open files, but apparently nothing to limit the amount of I/O.

You should handle the case manually as already described.